# Spark standalone, worker failed to connect to master

Tags: apache-spark

I'm in trouble with Spark. I have a Spark standalone cluster with 2 nodes,

- `master: 121.*.*.22(hostname is iZ28i1niuigZ)`
- `worker: 123.*.*.125(hostname is VM-120-50-ubuntu)`.

I have edited `slaves` file and added `123.*.*.125`.

There is no worker info on WebUI:

[WebUI image of spark master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap0Kl.png)

When executing the start script I see the following messages:

```
spark@iZ28i1niuigZ:~/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7$ sh sbin/start-all.sh
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /home/spark/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-spark-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-iZ28i1niuigZ.out
123.*.*.125: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /home/spark/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-spark-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-VM-120-50-ubuntu.out
```

The `spark-env.sh` file contents are:

```
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=121.*.*.22
export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
export SPARK_WORDER_INSTANCES=1
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1g
export JAVA_HOME=/home/spark/jdk1.8.0_101
```

On the worker I can see the following output:

```
Spark Command: /home/spark/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java -cp /home/spark/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/home/spark/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://iZ28i1niuigZ:7077 
========================================
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/11/30 20:04:56 INFO Worker: Started daemon with process name: 28287@VM-120-50-ubuntu
16/11/30 20:04:56 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
16/11/30 20:04:56 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
16/11/30 20:04:56 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
16/11/30 20:04:56 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/11/30 20:04:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: spark
16/11/30 20:04:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: spark
16/11/30 20:04:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
16/11/30 20:04:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
16/11/30 20:04:56 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(spark); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(spark); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/11/30 20:04:57 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkWorker' on port 41544.
16/11/30 20:04:57 INFO Worker: Starting Spark worker 10.141.120.50:41544 with 1 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
16/11/30 20:04:57 INFO Worker: Running Spark version 2.0.1
16/11/30 20:04:57 INFO Worker: Spark home: /home/spark/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7
16/11/30 20:04:57 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'WorkerUI' on port 8081.
16/11/30 20:04:57 INFO WorkerWebUI: Bound WorkerWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.141.120.50:8081
16/11/30 20:04:57 INFO Worker: Connecting to master iZ28i1niuigZ:7077...
16/11/30 20:04:58 WARN Worker: Failed to connect to master iZ28i1niuigZ:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$deploy$worker$Worker$$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(Worker.scala:216)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.jav    a:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to iZ28i1niuigZ/121.*.*.22:7077
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:228)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:179)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: iZ28i1niuigZ/121.*.*.22:7077
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        ... 1 more
16/11/30 20:05:08 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 1)
16/11/30 20:05:08 INFO Worker: Connecting to master iZ28i1niuigZ:7077...
16/11/30 20:05:08 WARN Worker: Failed to connect to master iZ28i1niuigZ:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout    .scala:75)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$deploy$worker$Worker$$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(Worker.scala:216)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to iZ28i1niuigZ/121.*.*.22:7077
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:228)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:179)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: iZ28i1niuigZ/121.*.*.22:7077
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        ... 1 more
```

The `/etc/hosts` on master node looks like:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
10.251.33.226 iZ28i1niuigZ
123.*.*.125 VM-120-50-ubuntu
```

And the `/etc/hosts` worker node contains the following configurations:

```
10.141.120.50 VM-120-50-ubuntu
127.0.0.1  localhost  localhost.localdomain
121.*.*.22 iZ28i1niuigZ
```

I cannot understand why the worker is unable to connect to master?

========================================================================
update:

I cannot `telnet 123.*.*.125 7077`, while I can `telnet 123.*.*.125`

When executing the command: `iptables -L -n`, I see the following messages:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination
```

Comment: Have you tried to check the firewall configuration? Try to telnet from the master from worker to port 7077 (`telnet <ip address> 7077`). And another thing.. it is not very wise to expose the public IPs of your servers though Internet.. I would recommend to edit your question and replace the IPs.

Comment: Please check `iptables`, requests may be blocked

Comment: @Serhiy I can not `telnet 123.*.*.125 7077`, but I can `telnet 123.*.*.125`. When executing the command: `iptables -L -n`, I see the following messages: `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) \n target prot opt source destination \n Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) \n target prot opt source destination \n Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) \n target prot opt source destination`